# List elements animation doesn't work when hide/show

Tags: javascript, animation, html-lists, show-hide, removeclass

Is it possible for li elements animation from here:

http://jsfiddle.net/8XM3q/light/

to animate when there is show/hide function used instead of remove? 
When i have changed "remove" to "hide" elements didn't move: http://jsfiddle.net/8XM3q/90/

I wanted to use this function for my content filtering animations - thats why i have to replace "remove" to "hide/show".

I'm not good at JS but i think that it counts all elements, even when they are hidden:

```
function createListStyles(rulePattern, rows, cols) {
var rules = [], index = 0;
for (var rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < rows; rowIndex++) {
    for (var colIndex = 0; colIndex < cols; colIndex++) {
        var x = (colIndex * 100) + "%",
            y = (rowIndex * 100) + "%",
            transforms = "{ -webkit-transform: translate3d(" + x + ", " + y + ", 0); transform: translate3d(" + x + ", " + y + ", 0); }";
        rules.push(rulePattern.replace("{0}", ++index) + transforms);
    }
}
var headElem = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0],
    styleElem = $("<style>").attr("type", "text/css").appendTo(headElem)[0];
if (styleElem.styleSheet) {
    styleElem.styleSheet.cssText = rules.join("\n");
} else {
    styleElem.textContent = rules.join("\n");
}
```

So my question is how to adapt that part of code to count only "show" (displayed) elements?

Comment: The problem here is that the CSS selector `".items li:nth-child({0})"` doesn't care if elements are hidden or not. As long as the element still exists, `nth-child` will count it. Counting the number of elements is the core of positioning in this code.

Comment: So it is impossible to apply/change that code to hide/show function?

Comment: I don't see any way of doing it this way (using only CSS rules, with nth-child and translate3d). May I ask you, `float` doesn't solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

I edited your jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/8XM3q/101/

notice that I changed this line:EDIT: http://jsfiddle.net/8XM3q/101/
 $(this).closest("li").remove();

to this:
`$(this).closest("li").hide("slow",function(){$(this).detach()});`

This means hide the item, speed = slow, when done hiding remove it.

Hope this is what you meant.

EDIT: Included detach.

Comment: I wanted to use this function for my content filtering animations - thats why i have to replace "remove" to "hide/show" I don't want to remove elements at all. Im sorry if I mislead You with my question.

Comment: if you don't want to remove at all, just hide then replace in my fiddle this `$(this).closest("li").hide("slow",function(){$(this).remove()});` with `$(this).closest("li").hide("slow");`

Comment: The element is hidden but elements after that element dont move to take it's place, like when I remove element.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have the animation and still have all of the data then use detach() function instead of remove: [jQuery - detach](https://api.jquery.com/detach/)

And to count or select elements try to do this using css's class attached to each element.

Comment: I think that is good answer but how make it work on my filtering site: http://jsfiddle.net/8u43sz53/ ? I tried to use detach() and append but elements didn't show up again.

Comment: Look here (it's the previous example): [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/v71kj4jn/) You can remember te element when detaching (like I do in the variable called _element_) and then use _append_ function to append this element in appropriate place. It's just an example so it remembers only the last deleted element, but I believe it shows how it works.

Comment: Thank You for explain :)

Answer (score 0):

[As per your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32584688/list-elements-animation-doesnt-work-when-hide-show#comment53023494_32584785):

> I wanted to use this function for my content filtering animations -
>   thats why i have to replace "remove" to "hide/show" I don't want to
>   remove elements at all. Im sorry if I mislead You with my question.

What you can do is to use a cache to store the list-items as they are hidden when you do the content filtering. Later when you need to reset the entire list, you can replenish the items from the cache.

Relevant code fragment...

*HTML*:

```
...
<button class="append">Add new item</button>
<button class="replenish">Replenish from cache</button>
<div id="cache"></div>
```

*JS*:

```
...
$(this).closest("li").hide(600, function() { 
    $(this).appendTo($('#cache')); 
});
...
$(".replenish").click(function () {
    $("#cache").children().eq(0).appendTo($(".items")).show();
});
```

**Demo Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/8XM3q/102/**

**Snippet**:

```js
$(function() {
    $(document.body).on("click", ".delete", function (evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest("li").hide(600, function() { 
            $(this).appendTo($('#cache')); 
  });
    });
    
    $(".append").click(function () {
        $("<li>New item  <a href='#' class='delete'>delete</a></li>").insertAfter($(".items").children()[2]);
    });
    $(".replenish").click(function () {
        $("#cache").children().eq(0).appendTo($(".items")).show();
    });

    // Workaround for Webkit bug: force scroll height to be recomputed after the transition ends, not only when it starts
    $(".items").on("webkitTransitionEnd", function () {
        $(this).hide().offset();
        $(this).show();
    });
});

function createListStyles(rulePattern, rows, cols) {
    var rules = [], index = 0;
    for (var rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < rows; rowIndex++) {
        for (var colIndex = 0; colIndex < cols; colIndex++) {
            var x = (colIndex * 100) + "%",
                y = (rowIndex * 100) + "%",
                transforms = "{ -webkit-transform: translate3d(" + x + ", " + y + ", 0); transform: translate3d(" + x + ", " + y + ", 0); }";
            rules.push(rulePattern.replace("{0}", ++index) + transforms);
        }
    }
    var headElem = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0],
        styleElem = $("<style>").attr("type", "text/css").appendTo(headElem)[0];
    if (styleElem.styleSheet) {
        styleElem.styleSheet.cssText = rules.join("\n");
    } else {
        styleElem.textContent = rules.join("\n");
    }
}

createListStyles(".items li:nth-child({0})", 50, 3);
```

```css
body { font-family: Arial; }
.items { 
    list-style-type: none; padding: 0; position: relative;
    border: 1px solid black; height: 220px; overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden;
    width: 600px;
}
.items li { 
    height: 50px; width: 200px; line-height: 50px; padding-left: 20px;
    border: 1px solid silver; background: #eee; box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; 
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out; transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}
div.cache { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="items">
    <li>Monday <a href="#" class="delete">delete</a>
    </li><li>Tuesday <a href="#" class="delete">delete</a>
    </li><li>Wednesday <a href="#" class="delete">delete</a>
    </li><li>Thursday <a href="#" class="delete">delete</a>
    </li><li>Friday <a href="#" class="delete">delete</a>
    </li><li>Saturday <a href="#" class="delete">delete</a>
    </li><li>Sunday <a href="#" class="delete">delete</a></li>
</ul>
<button class="append">Add new item</button>
<button class="replenish">Replenish from cache</button>
<div id="cache"></div>
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think your method is too complex (I don't mean complicated), and makes the code hard to understand when working on big projects. Would be simpler and easier to add a class "removed" then when we select elements not include elements with that class.

Comment: @LyesBEN: (1) This is not my code. I only made a couple of changes to solve Op's problem. (2) Have you read the question and did you try to understand what is the Op's problem?

Comment: Yes, you can check out my answer. Op wants to hide the element, but still not include it when looping through those elements. I quote "but i think that it counts all elements, even when they are hidden"

Comment: @LyesBEN: Good. So why don't you make a working demo from the Op's fiddle, and include it in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** There is a simpler way without adding any classes, is to use the [:visible](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) selector

You need to understand a concept is Javascript, which is that functions are considered objects. You can pass a function to another function, or return a function from a function.

Let's check the documentation on jQuery for the `hide` function

```
.hide( duration [, easing ] [, complete ] )
```

It says that it accepts a function as an argument for complete, which is called when the hide animation is complete.

The function `hide` does not remove the element from the DOM but simply "hides" it as the name suggests. So what we want to do, is hide the element then when the animation of hiding is done, we add a class "removed" to the list element.

We will accomplish that by passing a function (`complete` argument) like so :

```
$(this).closest("li").hide(400, function() {
  $(this).addClass('removed');
});
```

When you want to select the list elements that are not "removed", use this selector `$('li:not(.removed)')`